# Dlib "'dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h' file not found" Xcode C++ Console App

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dlib

I am struggling with Dlib C++ installation for a macOS application.
I am using Xcode,on the latest Catalina OS.

I installed Dlib using `brew install Dlib`. I also have X11 correctly installed and included from `/opt/X11/include/X11`.

Dlib library was installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.19/`, also included in my project's search paths (/include, /lib) , along with the preprocessor flags

```
DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT

DLIB_USE_BLAS

DLIB_USE_LAPACK

NDEBUG

DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
```

And still I am getting `dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h' file not found`.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By default, Xcode will not look inside `/usr/local/Cellar` . If you want Xcode to look inside `/usr/local/Cellar`, you must configure your project and specify that directory in the "Header Search Paths" build setting.

[image: Header search paths setting]